# Database Historical Data

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

How would I go about keeping track of a history of a database?  I would use it almost completely for statistical purposes.  For example it is easy enough to query the database to find out how many clients we currently have, but what if I want to compare how many clients we had last month compared to how many we have now?

I would assume I need another table to keep track of this info, and was wondering if there is some standard way to do it?

What I am thinking of is something like this:

```
id table_name column row_id value valid_from valid_to
```

Where valid_from would be when the data was inserted and valid_to would be the date the data could no longer be found in the database.

So for example I have table called teachers with a column status.  Within the status column a teacher could be "applying" "hired" "active" etc.  The change from one status to another would be saved in the above table with the column valid_to saving the date of when the teacher stopped having the status of "applying" and a new row would be created for "hired".  It seems like it would be fairly easy to query that table for statistical data.

But I really have no idea if this is a good way to go about it or not.  This is just what I came up with and may be a horrible way to do it.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

If it matters at all, I'm using MySQL and CakePHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will do what you want.

You can keep track of updates to that field by closing out the old `id` (setting `valid_to` to a date) and starting another one with the same `table_name`, `column`, and `row_id` and the new `value`.

Another way to do it is something like:

```
id entry_time table_name row_id column_name value
```

The first record for a particular `table_name` `row_id` and `column_name` is the creation of that record.  Subsequent records can be updates (non-null `value`) or deletions (null `value`).